# UI Freezing when NSPredicate changes with Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I've problem regarding to UI freezing when I pressed a button that try 
to change NSPredicate for Core Data fetch object it will hang for a while before 
it shows all of the data. This is especially when loading a tons of retrieve data.

As other app that load a lot of processing by pressing a button.

How do I should make the button that fires one operation by one operation? For example start the indicator, then mining the fetch object, then stop the indicator.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could have predicate change occur in background using the following NSObject method:
- (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg